# In ggplot2, are spaces in color names supported or not?

Tags: r, ggplot2

It seems that if I run this code on some machines (i.e. mine!), the points don't appear, but on some others (i.e. the students which prepared an R assignment), their points appear correctly as dark green...

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(msleep, aes(x = bodywt, y = brainwt)) +
geom_point(color = "dark green")
```

I'm running R 3.6.2 with ggplot2 3.2.1 whereas the colors appear correctly on R 3.6.1 with ggplot2 3.2.0

Comment: That's really weird! I've always used non-spaced colors from here: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf

Comment: What version of `ggplot2` are they using? [See also here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3644)

Comment: Yeah, from what @dario pointed out, this seems to be more likely related to `ggplot` version (and it's dependencies) than R version. It looks like long term the spaces should work but there was a release where that was broken. It's probably safe though to stick to the color names as given by `colors()` though.

Comment: Yeah, it seems it is related to an update in the scales package... 
https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3644#issuecomment-567468619

(link to a specific comment in @dario 's link